# How to I get my server to autoload my index.html?

Tags: homepage

I've recently been tasked to code a new site. The following is the URL for the site:

http://www.iss.guild.uwa.edu.au/2011/

As you can see going to the above URL will only lists the available files and folders in it. I want to get the server to autoload the index.html file like in www.iss.guild.uwa.edu.au/2010/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that your site is using apache. In the apache configuration file, add this line:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

and restart apache.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being obtuse but how exactly do you do that?

Comment: Oh and I don't exactly have full control of the server. I'm just given the storage space, I can't touch anything else.

Comment: Upload a file called .htaccess in the root directory with that line `DirectoryIndex index.html`. Note that: AllowOverride must be set to yes in the apache configuration file. If it is not, then you will have to ask the client to do one of the following 1) Put the DirectoryIndex line in the apache config and restart apache himself. 2) Atleast set AllowOverride appropriately.   But first, try uploading the .htaccess file to see if it works for you

Comment: It also might be worth adding `Options -Indexes` so that it doesn't show up the directory listing

Comment: Yup it works now thanks JP19. Oh and thanks for the tip too Piers. :)